# Calling Object inside of List

Tags: python, list

```
class MySong:
        _songTitle = "Song Title"   
        _artistName = "Artist Name"  
        _likeIndicator = -1         


    def setTitleAndArtist(self, songTitle, artistName):      
        self._songTitle = songTitle      
        self._artistName = artistName    

    def setLike(self, likeIndicator):                      
        self._likeIndicator = likeIndicator

    def undoSetLike(self, songTitle):                       
        Null

    def getTitle(self):
        return self._songTitle
    def getArtist(self):
        return self._artistName
    def getLikeIndicator(self):
        return self._likeIndicator


class MyPlaylist:
    _mySongs = [] 

    def add(self, song):                    
        self._mySongs.append(song)

    def showTitles(self):
        index = 0
        titlesList = []
        while index != len(self._mySongs):
            titlesList.append(self._mySongs[index].getTitle()) 
            index = index + 1
        return titlesList

    def remove(self):
        remindex = 0
        while remindex != len(self._mySongs):
            if (self._mySongs[index].getTitle()) == remChoice :
                return("Song FOUND debug!")
                self._mySongs.remove(index)

            else:
                remindex = remindex + 1
                return("Song NOT FOUND debug!")

    def getMySong(self):
        Null
```

There is a list of song objects inside of `_mySongs = []`. I'm trying to remove one, based on the title variable of that object.

In a separate (unshown) part of the program, the user is asked to enter the title of the song they want removed as a string. This is saved as `remChoice`.

I'm not entirely sure how to remove the song based on the title.
I've tried for a while to get it going, obviously we find the index of the song in the list by matching it to the title (by calling the getTitle method), then removing that index when it's found.

This isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete an item from a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) knowing it's index use:

```
del xs[i]
```

Where `i` is the index. (*e.g: Your song's index based on your search*).

`list.remove()` is used for removing a matching element form the list not the "ith" item.

You might also find that a `list` is not a suitable data structure here? Perhaps you could try storing key/value pairs in a `dict`. e.g:

```
my_songs = {}
my_aongs["My Song Title"] = MySong(title, description, length)
```

You can later delete songs via their keys:

```
del my_songs["My Song Title"]
```

where titles are your keys. This saves you from doing O(n) searching.

**Update:**

Your `.remove()` method should look more like the following:

```
def remove(self, title):
    for i, song in enumerate(self._mySongs):
        if song.getTitle() == title:
            del self._mySongs[i]
            return
    print("Song not found!")
```

Here we're using `list`'s iteration protocol by using a `for x in xs:` rather than using a while loop and doing manual bookkeeping. The builtin function `enumerate()` is also used to give us an index into the list we're iterating over (*i.e: it's position in the sequence*).

Comment: Hey James!  Ah I see how the list remove function isn't going to work here. Should be replaced with `del_mySongs[index]` ?

Comment: Precisely. As I said ``.remove(value)`` removes a value from the list. ``del xs[i]`` deletes the "ith" item in the list.

Comment: I see how you're thinking with the dict>list idea, but in this study, it needs to remain as a list with objects :-)

Comment: Perfect, this has solved everything!
Thankyou so much for your help James! 
I also realised that it'd need to be `del self.mySongs[remindex]

Comment: It's not necessary to copy the list if you're going to break out of the loop immediately after deleting an item. It's only if you want to keep iterating that you need to worry about the state of the iterator after the deletion. And even if you were going to do multiple deletions, copying the list won't be enough if you're deleting by index, as the indexes of the later items will shift after the previous ones are deleted. You'd need to use `self._mySongs.remove(song)` to have it work for multiple deletions (or iterate backwards and use negative indexing).

Answer (score 0):

try
`self._mySongs.remove(title)`
That should work.
(Or from another object: replace self by whatever your object name is)